# Javascript click count and submit to text area

Tags: javascript, click, counter

I am fairly new to coding and am attempting to learn to make a Chrome Plugin to add some functionality to a website. I have been struggling to find an answer to this and have searched and come up with quite a few different options, but nothing I can figure out to create what I am after.

What I and am looking to for is a script that will allow me to count the clicks of 5 different buttons, then send them to a textarea via a "submit" button.

[A] [B] [C] [D] [E] [send]

So if I were to click button A twice, C once and E three times then click "send" it would send it to my textarea and it would read "Counted A2 C1 E3" and would ignore anything that was not clicked. As a bonus, is it possible that when the text is sent to the textarea it would automatically submit?

Hope this makes sense and am looking forward to any help I may be able to get.

Regards,
Pazinga

Comment: Why do you want to have it both in textarea and submit? If you'd like it to stay visible, submit would have to happen in background.

Comment: Try to provide some code next time, as it is hard to exactly know what you mean.

Comment: I didn't submit any code because honestly I am terrible at coding at the moment. I have been attempting to learn for a couple days and am learning as much as I can, but apparently I am not very good at coding, so I sought help without trying to indicate I had too much understanding of coding, I am using the information from all these answer to learn more and try to become a better coder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is better, you can have as much buttons as you like!

update: Fix a bug that keys are unsorted (eg: Counted E3 C1 A2)

```
<html>
<head>  
<script>
    var list = {};
    function increaseCounter(variable) {
        if(!list[variable])
            list[variable]=1;
        else
            list[variable]++;
    }
    function send() {
        var keys = [];
        for(x in list)
            keys.push([x,list[x]]);
        keys.sort();

        var s = "Counted", i;
        for( i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
            s += " " + keys[i][0] + keys[i][1];
        document.getElementById('textarea').value = s;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>

<button onclick="increaseCounter('A')">A</button>
<button onclick="increaseCounter('B')">B</button>
<button onclick="increaseCounter('C')">C</button>
<button onclick="increaseCounter('D')">D</button>
<button onclick="increaseCounter('E')">E</button>

<button onclick="send()">Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: johnchen902, you have created exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can find a possible solution here : http://jsfiddle.net/jrm2k6/gv8vZ/

You can modify it at your convenience.

Here is the html used:

```
<button type="button" id="a">A</button>
<button type="button" id="b">B</button>
<button type="button" id="c">C</button>
<button type="button" id="d">D</button>
<button type="button" id="e">E</button>
<textarea rows="5" cols="40" id="results">
</textarea>
```

And the js part:

```
var buttonClicked = {"a":0, "b":0, "c":0, "d":0, "e":0};

$("button").click(function() {
  $("#results").text('');
  var clickedId = $(this).attr('id');
  buttonClicked[clickedId] +=1
  displayCounter();
});

function displayCounter()
{

    for(var elem in buttonClicked)
    {
        if (buttonClicked[elem] != 0)
        {
            $("#results").append(elem + " clicked " + buttonClicked[elem] + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: This works fine, but [TNW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2277221/tnw) gave another approach, more generic, here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xRMRP/

Comment: I'd see it in other way, using attributes. Look at http://jsfiddle.net/xRMRP/ - you don't need the dict anymore (and ids too), which is important when you want to add more buttons without hassle.

Comment: Great solution, I just wanted to give a quick approach, as Pazinga didn't provide any code, we shouldn't just do something perfect, as he will never really learn how to do it. I will edit my answer to redirect to your fiddle, as it is really good :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code it will help you:

```
<html>
<head>  

 <script>


  var A = 0;
    var B = 0;
    var C = 0;
    var D = 0;
    var E = 0;

    function increaseCounter(variable) {
        switch (variable) {
            case 'A':
                A++;
                break;
            case 'B':
                B++;
                break;
            case 'C':
                C++;
                break;
            case 'D':
                D++;
                break;
            case 'E':
                E++;
                break;
        }
    }


    function send() {

        var text='Counted ';
        if(A>0){
            text+=' A'+A;
        }
        if(B>0){
            text+=' B'+B;
        }
        if(C>0){
            text+=' C'+C;
        }
        if(D>0){
            text+=' D'+D;
        }
        if(E>0){
            text+=' E'+E;
        }
        document.getElementById('textarea').value =text;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>

<button onclick="increaseCounter('A')">A</button>
<button onclick="increaseCounter('B')">B</button>
<button onclick="increaseCounter('C')">C</button>
<button onclick="increaseCounter('D')">D</button>
<button onclick="increaseCounter('E')">E</button>

<button onclick="send()">Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use attributes of buttons to count clicks.

Comment: If I click button A twice, C once and E three times, it will produce `Counted A2 B0 C1 D0 E3`, while it should result in `Counted A2 C1 E3`.

Comment: Why not use an array or an object instead of 5 explicitely declared variables? What happens if you have 35 buttons for the switch? It will be too huge.